# Android Studio - JAVA - Variable might not have been initialized

Tags: java, android

I'm completely new to JAVA / Android so I take a course on udemy to learn that.
This is the code where I stuck:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.Random;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void guessclick(View view){
        int randomNumber;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Random rand = new Random();
        randomNumber = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
    }
}
```

This is **exactly** the same code which the teacher in the lesson video got and it works by him but I get `error: Variable randomNumber might not have been initialized` and when I put `randomNumber` in the "Toaster" and run the app is crash. Do someone know the solution? I found answers with same issue but with another codes and it didn't help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code is wrong and  won't compile. `int randomNumber;` declares a local variable that goes out of scope immediately after the `guessclick()` method returns. It's subsuquent use in `onCreate()` will not compile as that variable has not been declared in scope to that method.

I'm guessing they meant to declare `randomNumber` as an instance field of `MainActivity`,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        int randomNumber;
```

Comment: Ooops yes that's the solution, JAVA is pretty hard compared to PHP and JS :( countless extra code and classes for everything and weird rules :( Thanks :D

Comment: I'd wait until you master the language before you draw that conclusion. You simply declared a variable in the wrong scope. Are you saying PHP and JS don't have scopes?

Comment: I don't know what scope is but in JS for example you can define a variable outside any function and it will work in any function and no matter where. And in PHP it works no matter where and how defined (except it must be defined above where it will be used)

Comment: Almost everything which can also be done in PHP or JS is easier there

Comment: And in JAVA there are multiple types of arrays like what the.. let's see how much more weird stuff I'll find oO

Comment: @MatthiasMüller this is because Java has strict types / type safety. This is not weird but rather the standard. All common languages like C, C++, C# and Java have this.

Comment: @MatthiasMüller "in JS for example you can define a variable outside any function and it will work in any function and no matter where"- you DID NOT define the variable outside the function, you defined it inside the function. That was exactly your problem. The fix was just that, to define it outside the function.

Comment: @MatthiasMüller "Almost everything which can also be done in PHP or JS is easier there"- Words of wisdom from the guy that's been deeply involved with Java for half an hour now. Any other insights on the language you can share?

Comment: "you DID NOT define the variable outside the function, you defined it inside the function" but why is int randomNumber; even necessary when this variable is actually already dfined: randomNumber = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;

Comment: And the next what I found:

Comment: EditText hols = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nummernfeld);
int dienummer = Integer.parseInt(hols.getText().toString());

Comment: is in jQuery (JS):

Comment: dienummer = parseInt($('#nummernfeld').val());

Answer (score 2):

You can try:
Because you use "randomNumber" like global value

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    int randomNumber;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Random rand = new Random();
        randomNumber = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: As OP seems to be a beginner, this would require at least a single bit of explanation ..

Comment: Okay, I shall write him a explanation)

Comment: Sry Jeffrey was first :D

Comment: NOOOOOOOooooOOo

Comment: Good luck Muller!

Answer (score 0):

Because randomNumber is a local variable ,you can't use local variables outside it scope